# How to disable or remove the default.css, skin.css and portal.css in DNN for normal Users

Tags: html, asp.net, css, dotnetnuke

I have created the Project using DNN. I have written my CSS code in say "main.css". Firstly, I have created the HTML of the Project and then I have integrated it with DNN.

Now, the DNN default.css, skin.css and portal.css is overriding the main.css. **I need a way to that when I am logging in through admin then only "default.css, skin.css and portal.css" this CSS should get applied. Otherwise for Normal users it should not get applied..**

Simple flow of css to add

**Admin User** - default.css, skin.css , portal.css and main.css

Normal User - main.css

Hope My question is understandable..

Answer (score 3):

disable or remove the default.css, skin.css and portal.css in DNN for normal Users

For DNN 7 :-
[Disable/Remove unwanted (default) css files to be loaded in DotNetNuke (DNN)](http://www.gunaatita.com/Blog/Disable-Remove-unwanted-default-css-files-to-be-loaded-in-DotNetNuke-DNN-/1059)

For DNN 8:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#ControlBar_ControlPanel').length == 0) {
            $('head link[href*="/Resources/Shared/stylesheets/dnndefault/7.0.0/default.css"]').remove();
            $('head link[href*="/Resources/Shared/stylesheets/dnndefault/8.0.0/default.css"]').remove();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: For DNN 9:-


    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#personaBar-iframe').length == 0) {
            $('head link[href*="/Resources/Shared/stylesheets/dnndefault/7.0.0/default.css"]').remove();
            $('head link[href*="/Resources/Shared/stylesheets/dnndefault/8.0.0/default.css"]').remove();
        }
    });

Answer (score 2):

<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>

<dnn:DnnCssExclude runat="server" Name="dnndefault" />

Put those above in the page template file, like home.ascx, index.ascx.
It will remove default.css, can I ask you why are you going to remove it? it will cause an issue when you are trying to add a new module and you probably are not able to drag the module in the admin mode (I'm using DNN9.8)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will probably be to use the StyleHelper SkinObject https://stylehelper.codeplex.com/

Or some modified version of that.

Answer (score 0):

Default.aspx:
at first line replace *CodeBehind* with *CodeFile* attribute.

in Default.aspx.cs in OnPreRender method add at bottom:

```
var loader = Page.FindControl("ClientResourceIncludes");
var toRemove = new List<ClientDependencyInclude>();
foreach (ClientDependencyInclude ctl in loader.Controls)
{        
    if (ctl.FilePath.Contains("/Resources/Search/SearchSkinObjectPreview.css")
       || ctl.FilePath.Contains("/Portals/_default/admin.css"))
       toRemove.Add(ctl);
    }
}    

foreach (var ctl in toRemove)
    loader.Controls.Remove(ctl);
```

all error checking skipped for clarity

Answer (score 0):

@DamingZhang answer seems to me the more accurate.
Another option is to navigate to the file and clear its content. You may want to make a copy of the file first. I didn't.

Answer (score -3):

You could use php to add link tags for admin, something like

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION["pseudo"] = "admin") {
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portal.css">
<?php
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

Comment: It is in ASP.NET. I need a CMS way to do it.

Comment: My bad, didn't see it was in ASP.NET. But the idea is the same, store the type of session in the Session object, then dynamically load the link tags if it's an admin session.